# How Debezium connectors handles errors?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, debezium-engine

I am planning to use MySQL Debezium connector and have a question on the configuration for error handling.

Apache Kafka Connect have seems to have `errors.tolerance` property for error handling. And it is well explained in [blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/)

I am trying to understand is this applicable to Debezium connectors or not.

Answer (score 0):

That property applies to all Connectors, but of course it is up to each individual Connector class to define what is considered a retryable/tolerable error.